# What is the compatibility for F250 and F350 SD transmissions (2004 gas 5.4L)

Tags: ford, transmission, f-250, f-350, compatibility

I am considering purchasing a Ford 2004 F350 SD (automatic) with a tranny/engine light on. Assuming the worst, I am looking for donor transmissions (and transfer case possibly)

I think there is compatibility between a number of years and between F250 and F350 models.

I see indications of this online, but have not been able to satisfy myself 100%

Can someone confirm this or point me to a resource that will confirm?